# Problem with "discoursed of"

Tags: meaning, literature

I am reading Poe's "*The Murders in the Rue Morgue*" and am confused by the first sentence: "*The mental features discoursed of as the analytical, are, in themselves, but little susceptible of analysis.*

"I'm not sure  what "*themselves*" here  means and "*little susceptible of analysis*" sounds a little weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

*Discoursed of* = spoken of

*Themselves* refers to the 'features'

*Little susceptible of analysis* = not easy to analyse, or not suitable for analysis.

The whole passage is quite difficult to follow even to a native speaker.

Comment: ....So,what exactly does this passage say?...

Comment: _The ways of thinking which are described as 'analytical' are not, themselves, easy to analyse._  Perhaps you should be asking about this on a literature forum.

Comment: Maybe you are right. THX for the answering and reply,though.